# Releasing additional dependant assemblies to azure app service

Tags: .net-core, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines, .net-6.0

I have a dotnet 5 blazor app that has been getting built with an Azure DevOps build pipeline and released to an Azure App Service (IIS) with a separate release pipeline.

I want to get the app running on dotnet 6, so this is what I've done:

1. Changed the TargetFramework in the csproj
2. In the app service\general settings.Net Version, changed to ".Net 6 (Early Access)"
3. Added the following to the build pipeline

> task: UseDotNet@2   displayName: 'Use .NET Core sdk'   inputs:
> packageType: 'sdk'
> version: '6.0.x'
> includePreviewVersions: false

The build and release pipelines execute ok but when browsing to the newly deployed website, the following error is logged:

> Could not load file or assembly
> 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServices, Version=6.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot
> find the file specified

How should I get these newer versions of the nuget packages onto the app service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add a dedicated nuget restore dotnet cli task to the build pipline:

> task: DotNetCoreCLI@2   displayName: 'Restore Nuget Packages'
> inputs:
> command: 'restore'
> projects: '**/myProject.csproj'